# in the c++ hacker rank preperation cause, the last index returns 0 when i reverse it. but when i try the code out in visual studio, it works perfectly

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

**HERE IS THE QUESTION I FACED ON HACKERRANK.**

[the hackerrank question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CLPp.png)

**HERE IS THE CODE I PRINTED**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n;
    int array[n];
    int c,x;
    
    cin>>n; //inputting the array size
    n=n+1;
    int m=n;
    if(n>=1 && n<=1000 && m>=1 && m<=1000 )
    {
        for(c=1;c<=n;c++)//inutting the numbers
        {   if(c<=10000)
            {
                cin>>array[c];            
            }
    
        }
        
        for(x=m-1;x>=1;x--)//outputing the numbers reversed
        {
            cout<<array[x]<<" ";
        }        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

WHEN I GIVE INPUT THE ARRAY SIZE AS 4 AND THE DATA AS 1 4 3 2,
**ITS REVERSED AS 2,3,4,0**
BUT IT PERFECTLY GETS REVERSED WHEN COMPILED WITH VISUAL STUDIO CODE. WHYS THAT?? AND ALSO WHEN I SUBMIT CODE SEVERAL TESTS PASS, BUT SOME GET A SEGMENTATION ERROR

Comment: `array` initialized with size of what, exactly?

Comment: Also, out of bounds write and read. Variables declared outside their appropriate scope.  And poor formatting as the cherry on top.

Comment: As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined. (Use `std::vector`, and don't try to use a value before you know what the value is.)

Comment: This is an invalid code. You declare a variable n, without giving it a value. Then you declare the array[n]; which is of length n. If n is not defined, then how can you create the array with that capacity. Possibly, visual studio is initializing the variables explicitly and hence this is working on VS.

Comment: You know that `n<=1000`, and that `c<=n`. When do you think `c<=10000` is false?

Comment: _@Lakindu Perera_ could you please stop using all caps, or even worse, bold all caps in your posts here. This is considered shouting to people, and very unfriendly!

Comment: If you can C++ code in lowercase, then you can write English in lowercase too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, array should be initialized with a proper capacity. You should first read the size and then create the array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    // First read the array size and then create the array.
    cin>>n; //inputting the array size

    int array[n];

    //inputting the numbers
    // Remember indices go from 0 to N-1
    for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
    {
        cin>>array[c];
    }
    
    //outputing the numbers reversed
    for(int x=n-1;x>=0;x--)
    {
        cout<<array[x]<<" ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much dude, it worked, im still 2 months in with c++, sorry if my question was stupid